# PHP - Display all characters in html textarea (newline, whitespace included)

Tags: html, newline, whitespace

I have a text field in MySQL that contains an e-mail template.

I build an admin interface where the admin will be able to display the content in a `<textarea></textarea>` and edit it.

It works great, but I'd like to actualy see the whitespaces and the `\r\n`, something like Notepad++ "Show All Characters" button.

Here is the email template, as it is currently shown in `textarea`:

[image: html textarea]




And this is how I'd like to see it, like Notepad++ shows it, displaying the newlines and the whitespaces:

[image: notepad++ show all characters]

How can I do that using php? Should I just escape the `\r\n` from the database to make them to show up, or is there an other way?

**Update.**
I did manage to create a toggle button that displays whitespaces and newlines, even while typing.

**See example demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/80/


Here is where I found some of this interesting code: http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/03/javascript-change-entered-character-in.html

Comment: the `<textarea>` control cannot do this, you need to build your own custom control. php has nothing to do with it as it must be client side. maybe an existing WYSIWYG js editor will fit your needs.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with PHP or MySQL but is an HTML question - you should update your tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach:
before adding the text to the textarea you could make an replacement of the newline characters with some other "special" characters. Then at post before saving the content of textarea in mysql switch the "special" characters with the newline characters

Comment: You gave me a great idea, so I build my own style of editor. Simple but does what I want. I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TinyMCE. Here is the reference link http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Just give id to your text area like

```
<textarea id="tinyeditor" ></textarea>
```

In your script customize your requirement like

```
var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
    id: 'tinyeditor',
    width: 584,
    height: 175,
    cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
    controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
    rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
    dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
    controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
        'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
        'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'n',
        'font', 'size', 'style', '|', 'image', 'hr', 'link', 'unlink', '|', 'print'],
    footer: true,
    fonts: ['Verdana','Arial','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
    xhtml: true,
    cssfile: 'custom.css',
    bodyid: 'editor',
    footerclass: 'tinyeditor-footer',
    toggle: {text: 'source', activetext: 'wysiwyg', cssclass: 'toggle'},
    resize: {cssclass: 'resize'}
});
```

And last get value from data base in textarea on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var template_data = '<?php echo $database_result; ?>';
    $("iframe").contents().find("#editor").html(template_data);  
});
```

Comment: I was happy to see that this editor has the option of displaying hidden characters, exactly as I'd like to. Unfortunately I didn't get this functionality it to work.

Comment: Have you added jquery in your page which are given on website? 1) tiny.editor.js 2) tiny.editor.packed.js

Comment: Yes, of course. The editor is working great, apart from that function and I couldn't figure out why.